# Initialization value (IV) bit error

Tags: encryption

When a bit error happens in an IV, what would the result of decrypting a cipher-text be in the different encryption modes like ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB, and CTR?

Answer (score 6):

This seems a strange question to ask. Is it for an assignment or are you trying to select the best mode for a particular application? Regardless:

1. **ECB** does not use an IV.
2. **CTR** has a nonce value, which could be considered an IV. A bit error there will produce an entirely different key stream for every block.
3. **CBC** and **CFB** will corrupt the first plaintext block, but thereafter it is OK.
4. In the case of **OFB**, I believe the entire plaintext will be corrupted because the entire stream of data is determined by the IV (plus the key, of course).

Comment: CTR does use an IV (the nonce), and a bit error there will produce an entirely different key stream for every block.

Comment: @mfanto I've edited my answer to include that, thanks.